# Why I can't build path for a project that was cloned from Github in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, github, clone

I cloned a project of my teams from Github using a link to my Folder Java. I only used the Clone tools in Eclipse and added it to my Package Explorer as a General Project. But when I open the project, all the package became normal folder, I click into the folder to the Build Path but there's nothing I can't do. I don't understand why, please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a Maven project using the smart import might help.

[image]

Comment: yes I use that smart import but it's not work

Comment: thank you very much now I can do it <3